# Android GPUImage filter equivalent of Instagram's "Fade"?

Tags: android, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

We're using the well-known image processing library `GPUImage` as ported for Android.

The one here: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

Most of our desired controls have obvious equivalents in `GPUImage`; brightness is `GPUImageBrightnessFilter`, sharpen is `GPUImageSharpenFilter`, etc.

What, however, is the equivalent of Instagram's *Fade*?

We're sure that *Fade* is just a pretty word for some type of colour desaturation of sorts, but we're not quite sure.

Maybe `GPUImageSaturationFilter` with specific parameters? Or something more custom?

**Part 2**

While I'm at it - same question, but for *Warmth* aka *Temperature*.

We're using `GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter` as it appears to be "kelvin-based" and seems to be the closest thing to *Warmth*.

Thank you!